# Joining points in multi-series seaborn pointplot

Tags: python, seaborn

i am having some trouble with a seaborn pointplot.

I am to plot the Temperature vs. growth rate of four kinds of bacteria, so that each type has its own graph, but all four are in the same plot. The thing is, i cannot connect the individual points, i can only get the individual points.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats, integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import seaborn as sns

dataSorted=data.sort_values(['Temperature','Growth_rate'],ascending=[True,True])
plt.subplots()    
ax2=sns.pointplot(x='Temperature',y='Growth_rate', hue='Bacteria' ,data=dataSorted,scale=0.7,join=True)
axes2=ax2.axes
axes2.set_xlim(10,60)
axes2.set_ylim(0,1.5)
axes2.set_xticks(np.arange(1,7)*10)
axes2.set_xticklabels(np.arange(1,7)*10)
```

The output is exactly as specified, apart from the lines between points:
[My plot - without lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHhqb.png)
I have no idea how to fix this, i have even set the "join" parameter manually, even though it is set as True by default.

Comment: The points which are adjacent to each other in your `order` parameter are connected if you look closely. The problem is that the jointplot doesn't interpolate for missing data, so then the points just don't get connected. I would also like to know how to fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting categorical plots with point plot in seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46795504/plotting-categorical-plots-with-point-plot-in-seaborn)