# Connecting non-adjacent data points in Seaborn pointplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot categorical plots with the Seaborn pointplot, but data points that are not adjacent are not connected with a line in the plot. I would like to interpolate between non adjacent points, and connect them in the same way as adjacent points are connected, how can I do this?

An example: In the left and middle images, the blue and green points should be connected with a curve, respectively, but now they are separated into small parts. How can I plot the left and middle images just like the right one?

[image]

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(10,5))
exp_methods = ['fMRI left', 'fMRI right', 'MEG']
for i in range(3):
    experiment = exp_methods[i]
    dataf = df[df['data']==experiment]    
    sns.pointplot(x='number_of_subjects', y='accuracy', hue='training_size', data=dataf,
               capsize=0.2, size=6, aspect=0.75, ci=95, legend=False, ax=axs[i])
```

Comment: I would suggest not to use seaborn then. Just use a usual scatter or line plot with errorbars in matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an option to interpolate where there are missing data points, and hence the line stops instead. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37857577/joining-points-in-multi-series-seaborn-pointplot) on the same topic from 2016 remains unanswered.

Instead, you could use `plt.errorbar` as suggested in the comments, or add the lines afterwards using `plt.plot` while still using seaborn to plot the means and error bars:

```
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

# Create a gap in the data and plot it
tips.loc[(tips['size'] == 4) & (tips['sex'] == 'Male'), 'size'] = 5
sns.pointplot('size', 'total_bill', 'sex', tips, dodge=True)
```

[image]

```
# Fill gap with manual line plot
ax = sns.pointplot('size', 'total_bill', 'sex', tips, dodge=True, join=False)

# Loop over the collections of point in the axes and the grouped data frame
for points, (gender_name, gender_slice) in zip(ax.collections, tips.groupby('sex')):
    # Retrieve the x axis positions for the points
    x_coords = [coord[0] for coord in points.get_offsets()]
    # Manually calculate the mean y-values to use with the line
    means = gender_slice.groupby(['size']).mean()['total_bill']
    ax.plot(x_coords, means, lw=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I have another question, on the left and middle images, the gap between two adjacent values on the x-axis should be different, but now they are same, how can I change that?

Comment: @emmaqqq No worries, please accept this answer (click the checkmark) if it solved your problem. Then I can close the question I linked to as a duplicate of this. For your comment, please open a new question and feel free to link it here.

Comment: @emmaqqq I forgot to say: For your new question, try to include a sample data set, so that it easy for others to reproduce your problem and help you. A good resource are the Seaborn sample data sets, feel free to reuse code from my answer here.